# POSTGRESQL: ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Tags: postgresql, upsert

[image]I am trying to perform upsert operation against a table named "message_payload", using below query, but get the error:

> ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
>   SQL state: 42P10

Query:

```
    INSERT INTO public.error_message(
    id, created_by, created_dt, modified_by, modified_dt, attempt, message_headers, 
    message_main_topic, message_payload, message_status, message_status_code)
        VALUES (51, null, null, null, null, 1, '{
        "jsonContent": {
            "content-length": "1635",
            "message_status_code": "417",
            "cookie": "JSESSIONID=279AF4C174E6192BDAB11A067768BBD5",
            "postman-token": "f0f33e86-498f-452a-aaf6-18eb84dc5907",
            "kafka_timestampType": "CREATE_TIME",
            "message_id": "21",
            "kafka_receivedMessageKey": "null",
            "kafka_receivedTopic": "error-topic",
            "accept": "*/*",
            "kafka_offset": "33",
            "kafka_consumer": "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer@5091bb5f",
            "host": "localhost:8082",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "connection": "keep-alive",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "kafka_receivedPartitionId": "0",
            "kafka_receivedTimestamp": "1552305428711",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "message_main_topic": "ldarsQCustomStatistics.1",
            "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.6.1"
        }
    }', 'ldarsQCustomStatistics.1', '{
        "jsonContent": {
            "messageTime": 16772223422,
            "messageRev": 9,
            "businessId": "DB",
            "messageId": "55"
        }
    }', 1, 201)
    ON CONFLICT ((message_payload->'jsonContent'->>'message_id'))
    DO UPDATE SET attempt = error_message.attempt + 1, message_headers = EXCLUDED.message_headers, 
                  message_status_code = EXCLUDED.message_status_code, message_status = EXCLUDED.message_status, 
                  created_by = EXCLUDED.created_by, created_dt = EXCLUDED.created_dt, 
                  modified_by = EXCLUDED.modified_by, modified_dt = EXCLUDED.modified_dt, 
                  message_main_topic = EXCLUDED.message_main_topic, message_payload = EXCLUDED.message_payload, 
                  id = DEFAULT
```

Comment: could you post the table specification of `public.error_message`?

Comment: oh pg_admin. Then you need also to show the `constraints` tab. ^^

Comment: Please show us the `create table` statement including all indexes and constraints as formatted text not some screen shot showing some column names.

Comment: The table was created using spring data jpa using hibernate entities. So i did not create any additional indexes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are most likely missing a unique constraint on this particular field.

Example:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX j_msgid_idx ON public.error_message((data->'jsonContent'->>'message_id'));
```

Comment: Somebody might get confused, so, while this answer is correct the usage of the words "unique constraint" sent me down a rabbit hole to find that you can do this too: `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT constriant_name ...`, but `j_msgid_idx` is NOT a constraint here. It is an index to cause.... constraint.?